# How to know the timezone used by any web site?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, timezone

How to know the timezone used by any website that you are scraping. Is there any way we can find if it is necessary to know the timezone?

Comment: In general: you cannot do it. Webservers are "virtual" things. Most web servers put in headers the date UTC, and now we use a lot webfarms and CDN, so the location of server is unknown, or different from the administrator setting. You may get more luck with geolocating the IP address. There are many libraries for that.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi—even if geolocation via IP address was accurate (it seriously isn't) most servers are set to UTC anyway because, as you say, they might be anywhere in the world and UTC provides a convenient epoch.

Comment: To echo the others, this is an impossible task.  For example, what time zone would you expect to return given `https://www.google.com`?

Answer (score 0):

If website calls on your nodejs server, you can send it into header from website to on your server, to get timezone on website this migt will help you.

`Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`